# Change backgroundcolor of a layout after starting an other activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new with Android and I'm not able to do this properly.

I have a Layout, which has a setOnTouchListener,

```
 arg0.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4096EE"));
 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddWebsiteActivity.class);
 NewsRecoveryActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```

But I want to restore the background of my layout after I start my other activity because if i go back it's like i'm touching my layout... how can i do that ?

Thank you in advance

Edit : Selector result :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/add_website_layout"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/selector_add_website"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
 >
```

When i remove the background line it's working.

Comment: wait will give a perfect selector.xml file that was only sample looking to that you must create as you required

Comment: try now whether it worked now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Agarwal to help me, solution :

In the view add

```
android:background="@drawable/selector_add_website"
```

selector_add_website in drawable folder

```
<selector
 android:id="@+id/selector_add_website"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@color/black" />
<!-- Pressed -->
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@color/bluefocused" />
</selector>
```

color.xml in values folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <color name="black">#ff000000</color> 
 <color name="bluefocused">#4096EE</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selector for and setbackground that selector. so that on touch the color changes automatically and restore.

```
<selector
    android:id="@+id/myselector"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Non focused states -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="#FF0000" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="#FF0000" />

    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="#FF0000" />
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="#FF0000" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="#FF0000" />
</selector>
```

can change color as required.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/blue" />
    <item android:state_selected="true" 
        android:drawable="@color/red" />
</selector>
```

use the above selector

Comment: I didn't know selector until now, but my app crash when I try to correspond the selector to my layout.

I use : android:background="@drawable/selector_add_website" then i create a selectora_dd_website.xml in drawable with your example as content, but crash crash and crash.

Comment: have you placed your selector in drawable folder

Comment: You are too fast, I dont have time to edit, yes my selector is in the drawable folder.

Comment: First post edited. Btw, I removed all android:drawable="#FF0000" from your example, Eclipse doesnt like it.

Comment: have you replaced this line android:drawable="#FF0000" because you cant directly have color code like this

Comment: thats the mistake you did. that time i forget to mention create colors.xml file in values folder and place all color code in and in selector use it as @colors/red

Comment: I have something like this now : android:drawable="@color/blue", and in color.xml : <color name="blue">#ffccddff</color>. But it did nothing when it's focused.

Comment: If I change the non focused state to blue, it's working, my layout is blue, but not the others when I try to touch my layout.